# Android - Accelerometer fall detection algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math, accelerometer

I'm trying to build an app for fall detection using the accelerometer of a smartphone as a school project (so I still have a lot of things to improve).
I was doing some research and I found this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13678-016-0004-1) with some calculations, so I'm trying to turn those into some code.

I asked a friend for some help and he explained me how to do those calculations. But considering it's been a few years since I finished high school and I'm not very good at math, I'm sure I got some stuff wrong. 
So I was expecting someone could give me a hand.

Here's what I need and what I have already, in case someone finds any mistake.

[image: Feature SV (sum of the components of the acceleration vector)]

```
return Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z);
```

[image: Feature AV (angle variation)]

```
    double anX = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.X) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.X);
    double anY = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y);
    double anZ = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z);
    double an = anX + anY + anZ;

    double anX0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.X), 2);
    double anY0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y), 2);
    double anZ0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z), 2);
    double an0 = Math.sqrt(anX0 + anY0 + anZ0);

    double anX1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.X), 2);
    double anY1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y), 2);
    double anZ1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z), 2);
    double an1 = Math.sqrt(anX1 + anY1 + anZ1);

    double a = an / (an0 * an1);

    return (Math.pow(Math.cos(a), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

[image: Feature C A (change in angle)]

```
    double aX = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.X) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.X);
    double aY = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y);
    double aZ = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z);

    double a0 = aX + aY + aZ;

    double a1 = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aX, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aY, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aZ, 2)));

    return (Math.pow(Math.cos(a0 / a1), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

I'm getting the same return from the second and the third calculation and neither seems to be the expected result, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code for the class, for more details

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.activity.FallNotificationActivity;
import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.model.Elderly;
import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.model.Person;
import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.model.User;
import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.util.AccelerometerAxis;
import br.com.aimcol.fallalertapp.util.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory;

public class FallDetectionService extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener {


    private static final int ACCELEROMETER_SAMPLING_PERIOD = 1000000;
    private static final double CSV_THRESHOLD = 23;
    private static final double CAV_THRESHOLD = 18;
    private static final double CCA_THRESHOLD = 65.5;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private User user;
    private Gson gson;

    private Long lastSentInMillis;
    private Long minTimeToNotifyAgain = 3000000L;

    private List<Map<AccelerometerAxis, Double>> accelerometerValues = new ArrayList<>();


    public FallDetectionService() {
        super(".FallDetectionService");
    }

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public FallDetectionService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,
                                        int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];

        if (this.isFallDetected(x, y, z)) {
            if (this.isOkayToNotifyAgain()) {
                this.lastSentInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FallNotificationActivity.startFallNotificationActivity(this, this.gson.toJson(this.user));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isFallDetected(double x,
                                double y,
                                double z) {

        double acceleration = this.calculateAcceleration(x, y, z);// - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        this.addAccelerometerValuesToList(x, y, z, acceleration);

        String msg = new StringBuilder("x: ").append(x).append(" y: ").append(y).append(" z: ").append(z).append(" acc: ").append(acceleration).toString();
        Log.d("FDS-Acc-Values", msg);

        if (acceleration > CSV_THRESHOLD) {
//            double angleVariation = this.calculateAngleVariation();
//            if (angleVariation > CAV_THRESHOLD) {
//                double changeInAngle = this.calculateChangeInAngle();
//                if (changeInAngle > CCA_THRESHOLD) {
                    Log.d("FDS-Fall-Happened", msg);
                   return true;
//                }
//            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void addAccelerometerValuesToList(double x,
                                              double y,
                                              double z,
                                              double acceleration) {
        if(this.accelerometerValues.size() >= 4) {
            this.accelerometerValues.remove(0);
        }
        Map<AccelerometerAxis, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(AccelerometerAxis.X, x);
        map.put(AccelerometerAxis.Y, y);
        map.put(AccelerometerAxis.Z, z);
        map.put(AccelerometerAxis.ACCELERATION, acceleration);
        this.accelerometerValues.add(map);
    }

    private double calculateAcceleration(double x,
                                         double y,
                                         double z) {
        return Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z);
    }

    private double calculateAngleVariation() {
        int size = this.accelerometerValues.size();
        if (size < 2){
            return -1;
        }

        double anX = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.X) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.X);
        double anY = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y);
        double anZ = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z);
        double an = anX + anY + anZ;

//        double an = this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.ACCELERATION) * this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.ACCELERATION);

        double anX0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.X), 2);
        double anY0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y), 2);
        double anZ0 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -2).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z), 2);
        double an0 = Math.sqrt(anX0 + anY0 + anZ0);

        double anX1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.X), 2);
        double anY1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y), 2);
        double anZ1 = Math.pow(this.accelerometerValues.get(size -1).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z), 2);
        double an1 = Math.sqrt(anX1 + anY1 + anZ1);

        double a = an / (an0 * an1);

        return (Math.pow(Math.cos(a), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI); //cosseno inverso? Ou cosseno ^-1?
    }

    private double calculateChangeInAngle() {
        int size = this.accelerometerValues.size();
        if (size < 4){
            return -1;
        }
        double aX = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.X) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.X);
        double aY = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.Y);
        double aZ = this.accelerometerValues.get(0).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z) * this.accelerometerValues.get(3).get(AccelerometerAxis.Z);

        double a0 = aX + aY + aZ;

        double a1 = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aX, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aY, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aZ, 2)));

        return (Math.pow(Math.cos(a0 / a1), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (this.user == null) {
            String userJson = intent.getStringExtra(User.USER_JSON);
            this.user = this.gson.fromJson(userJson, User.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,
                              int flags,
                              int startId) {

        if (this.gson == null) {
            RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Person> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                    .of(Person.class, "type")
                    .registerSubtype(Elderly.class, Elderly.class.getSimpleName());
            this.gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory).create();
        }

        if (this.user == null) {
            String userJson = intent.getStringExtra(User.USER_JSON);
            this.user = this.gson.fromJson(userJson, User.class);
        }

        this.mSensorManager = (SensorManager) super.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        this.mAccelerometer = this.mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if (this.mAccelerometer == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Acelerometro não encontrado");
        }

        this.mSensorManager.registerListener(this, this.mAccelerometer, ACCELEROMETER_SAMPLING_PERIOD);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private boolean isOkayToNotifyAgain() {
        return this.lastSentInMillis == null || (this.lastSentInMillis + this.minTimeToNotifyAgain) < System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static void startFallDetectionService(String userJson,
                                                 Context context) {

        Intent fallDetectionServiceIntent = new Intent(context, FallDetectionService.class);
        fallDetectionServiceIntent.putExtra(User.USER_JSON, userJson);
        context.startService(fallDetectionServiceIntent);
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
    protected boolean testFallDetection(List<Map<AccelerometerAxis, Double>> values) {
        for (Map<AccelerometerAxis, Double> value : values) {
            if (this.isFallDetected(
                    value.get(AccelerometerAxis.X),
                    value.get(AccelerometerAxis.Y),
                    value.get(AccelerometerAxis.Z))) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ps: Sorry if I got something wrong. English is not my first language and I'm a little rusty.

Ps2: Sorry about my variable names.

Ps3: The code is on [github](https://github.com/camilobmoreira/FallAlertApp/tree/dev), if you want to take a look on the rest of the code or if instead of posting a reply here you want to make a pull request or something, feel free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might not be appropriate here.  SO isn't intended as a code review site.

Here are a few comments to consider:

1. The first formula you list is not what you've expressed in code.  There is no square root or sum of squares in the formula, but you put them into code for some reason.  The article says SV should be the sum of the absolute value of the components of the linear acceleration vector.  That's not what your code says.
2. The meaning of n and n+1 in the second formula isn't clear to me.  Are those consecutive time points?  The dot product of two vectors is easy to calculate - but for which two vectors?
3. The third formula calls for an average of acceleration vectors over a four second window.  I don't see that being done anywhere.  The number of vectors involved in the average would depend on your sampling rate.

I would suggest that you re-read the article several more times.

I'd also advise that you encapsulate these into functions and write some good unit tests for them.  See if you can reproduce the results from the paper.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry about that.
And thanks for your comments.